# How can i refresh my audio devices from within windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, audio, tv

I have a media server running Windows 8.1, It is connected to an A/V Receiver which is then connected to my TV.

My A/V Receiver has a pass-through mode so if i just want to use TV Audio which i usually use for TV Shows then i just use that pass-through mode, However when i want to watch a movie i turn the A/V Receiver on so i get Surround sound.

I'm having an issues where if i watch a movie, Then later on try and watch a TV episode without having the receiver on it doesn't pick up the audio source unless i restart the PC.

If i sign into the Media Server using remote desktop then close the connection that also refreshes the audio source, this is my only work-around currently.

Is there a way to make a BAT file to disable / re-enable my audio so i can get audio again ?

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years old, but I found the solution to this. I have had a similar problem for about a year. First, press `Win + R`, then type `control`. Press enter, and then you are in the old control panel. Click on `Hardware and Sound`, then `Sound`. This opens another window and should refresh the sound device list. From there, you can select your sound device as the default, or restart the new settings app. Your sound devices should appear.

This has been done on Windows 10, but I'm sure it would work on Windows 8+.